# Angular. How to conditionally import the Kendo UI JQuery file for production only

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui

You can conditionally import a reference in Angular by using ESNext in the tsconfig.json file instead of es2015, and then by using something like

```
import("./path").then(x=> {

});
```

The import for KendoUI Jquery looks like

import '@progress/kendo-ui';

and doesn't work with the syntax above (index.d.ts is not a module)

NB Kendo UI does have an Angular version, using the JQuery version is a stopgap measure for some of the missing controls until the Angular version is ready)

(Why? Because this Angular project will be hosted inside an existing web page which already imports KendoUI, weird I know, but it will be developed in a separate standalone project)

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of hidden away in other questions

In Angular 7 there is a folder, environments, with 2 files: environment.ts, environment.prod.ts. One for development, one for production. You can also add others

You can place an import in the environment.ts file and then it won't import in the release build